# Request : Python 3.8 : install pyopenjtalk and htsengine

Tags: python-3.8

I want to install pyopenjtalk, but it's require VSbuild 14+ or VS2022 program (cmake, nmake) to build pyd file, the program installer size is 6GB.

And... my Hard disk almost full... so yeah.

Request :

1. install pyopenjtalk on python 3.8,
2. go to C:\Users\#username#\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\pyopenjtalk\
3. zip down all files, and sent the download link to me. thanks.

maybe you have another solution?

error :

```
Using cached pyopenjtalk-0.3.0.tar.gz (1.5 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [25 lines of output]
      setup.py:26: DeprecationWarning: distutils Version classes are deprecated. Use packaging.version instead.
        _CYTHON_INSTALLED = ver >= LooseVersion(min_cython_ver)
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\Beatz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\Beatz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "C:\Users\Beatz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "C:\Users\Beatz\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vs065sx6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 162, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(
        File "C:\Users\Beatz\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vs065sx6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 143, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\Beatz\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vs065sx6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 267, in run_setup
          super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
        File "C:\Users\Beatz\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vs065sx6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 158, in run_setup
          exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
        File "setup.py", line 153, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\Beatz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 489, in run
          with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
        File "C:\Users\Beatz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
          self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
        File "C:\Users\Beatz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
          hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
      FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```